# How can one make a secure gap-fill password system?

Tags: php, security, passwords, password-protection, password-encryption

I am  working on a php login system and I was wondering how it is possible to make a secure password entry system that asks for say the 1st, 2nd and 8th characters of your password, like many online banking systems do. How could one make this *and* have the passwords stored as double-salted hashes?

Comment: Banks store these entries where they ask for individual letters from a word or phrase as encrypted values, not as hashes

Comment: could you explain more on this..

Comment: You cant ask the user for single characters and compare them to fully salt-hashed strings as the strings and salts itself depend on the result of the whole hash.

Comment: But how can that be secure as if the keys are stolen, all the passwords are compromised!

Comment: C4ud3x I understand that but then how is it done?

Comment: You could hash all single characters and save them to your database :). Or rather hash all characters and append all hashes to one big string into your db? :)

Comment: You will likely have to store each character of the password separately using encryption.  This may actually weaken your overall security scheme, because if an attack gets your database, now they have a second means of obtaining the original passwords.

Comment: I am now very concerned for my password's security

Comment: Its very easy. Single characters cant be compared with hashed strings. Only with encrypted strings. The only possibility with hashing would be indeed to save the single characters hashed inside your database. I have to append... I dont know any banks here in germany which ask for single characters.

Comment: All these methods seem far more insecure than a normal password system!

Comment: Yeah right. A single hashed character isnt that secure according the needed power to decrypt it. As no one noticed it: It would for sure also depend on the algorithm.

Comment: I know! I am wondering if people are actually making themselves less secure by using this method?

Comment: As I said I dont even know banks which are using such a system. ^^ Anyway.. I cant imagine how this should be done without loosing the strenght of security.

Comment: My bank uses that system, but as a second step in a two-step login.... they still have a full password as the initial step

Comment: Then maybe they keep the previous entered input temporarly(before hash comparison) then insert the given characters in the previously inputted password at the asked position and then perform the hash comparison on the new password(the one with the substituted characters). However, an attacker who knows that you used this method will keep the password and catch the first step success => Not safe.

Comment: The `x from n` value isn't the same as the password value at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An idea that comes into my mind is to store every character of the password hashed on separate field or serialized:

**PSEUDOCODE:**

$password is the user password, $secret_word is the word you use to check single characters

```
function get_hashed_characters($password, $secret_word) {
    $char_store = ""

    for every character $char in $secret_word
        $hashed_char = some_hash_function($char + $password)
        $hash_store = $char_store + $hashed_char

    return $hash_store
}

function check_hashed_char($password, $hash_store, $char_index, $char) {
    if len($hash_store) < $char_index * $HASH_LEN + $HASH_LEN return false

    $hashed_char = substr($hash_store, $char_index * $HASH_LEN, $HASH_LEN)

    return true if $hashed_char is equals to some_hash_function($char + $password), false otherwise
}
```

**UPDATE:** as C4ud3x pointed out, I hash both the character I want to store concatenated with the password

This is a completely different solution sometimes used on Linux systems: [Challenge-Response authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Challenge%E2%80%93response_authentication)

Comment: I wonder how much security would be added if, instead of hashing $char + $password, one uses $password to encrypt $char, like some_hash_functions(symmetric_encrypt($char, $password)).

Comment: How do you get the $password when you are checking the input

Answer (score 0):

HSBC use this style of password system on their website: [image: website]

and in their app: [image: App])*

After contacting them they said:

> Ensuring the security of our systems is and will continue to be our number one priority.
>
> All the details that are sent to and from our systems are encrypted
> using high encryption levels.  As long as you keep your log on
> information secret, we can assure you that the service is secure.  As
> you will appreciate, we cannot provide further details about the
> additional security measures used by Online Banking, as we must
> protect the integrity of the system.

Though this could just be a reference to their use of SSL, I think it probably suggests they:

- Encrypt password data in the database
- Encrypt the passwords in the database and then encrypt the whole database for better security.

I think the best solution is that provided by [ColOfAbRiX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29700262/3088158), as it doesn't require encryption (which without the technologies available to banks such as HSBC is probably not very secure).

Comment: Encryption is still insecure compared to hashing. I don't like it. When they say encryption they might not mean actual encryption. They might just say that because people don't know what hashing is

Comment: @VogonJeltz My email specifically referred to Hashing and Encryption so I think their response referred to encryption deliberately. I agree, I don't like encryption, but I am sure their decisions will be reasoned and correct.